# change back button arrow color in ionic 3

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

How to change back button color in ionic 3? (From white to black color). It's screenshot with this button:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change it by just using css. Place the following style rule in the `app.scss` file:

```
ion-header ion-icon.back-button-icon.icon {
    color: map-get($colors, dark);
}
```

That would use the *dark* color from your `$colors` array (`variables.scss` file):

```
$colors: (
  //...
  dark:       #222
);
```

Comment: thankyou, its work :D, but, where i can found to change back button color documentation ?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't such documentation. The back arrow should be styled just like the page title. I'm not sure if in your case there's a css style rule somewhere in the code that tried to change the color of some icons only, and changed it for all the icons instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can just do it by using the css.

```
.back-button-icon-md {
  color: darkblue;
}
```

Note: `md` is for android . For ios replace `md` to `ios`, For windows replace `md` to `wp`.

Comment: Not sure why you don't just target `.back-button`

Comment: How can you do this in type script, to change the color of the back button based on user interaction?